# How to pass a username from a Sublayout to the current Layout in Sitecore?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, sitecore

In my Sitecore solution I want to display the username of the logged in user on the Layout. The username has been determined within a Sublayout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to use something as simple as

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User 
or
Sitecore.Context.User.Name
```

within your Layout aspx page.

If this doesn't work for you, you could consider [raising an event from your Sublayout and handle that within the Layout](http://www.matthewdresser.com/sitecore/pass-data-between-sublayouts). In your eventArgs you would pass the name (of the current user, as determined in the Sublayout). Essentially you use Sitecore's event pooling functionality with API calls such as

```
//in the sublayout
Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent("eventName", someObject);

//in the Layout
Sitecore.Events.Event.Subscribe("eventName", eventHandlerRef);//where eventHandlerRef is a method with the parameters (object, EventArgs)
Sitecore.Events.Event.Unsubscribe("eventName", eventHandlerRef);
```